# Access Query last character omitting

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to write a query which on run will compare two string excluding the last charater. eg.
I have in Database newyorkA, in the search text i want to search excluding A in the last, i.e newyork only so how can i write this in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select left(columnname, len(columnname) - 1) as AllCharsExceptOne from tablename
```